# subprocess call avoid stopping after error

Tags: python, subprocess

I call a program a `subprocess.call()` in a for-loop and then it does something. However, after the called program crashes (no, I can't avoid that) the python script terminates.

The code:

```
with open("runtests.output", "w") as output:
    for i in range(1,5):
        for j in range(2,5):
            subprocess.call(["runprogram", "with", "arguments"])
            output.write(str(i) + str(j))
            output.write(str(resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_CHILDREN)))
            output.write("\n")
```

In this case, `runprogram with arguments` fails at some point, i.e. at the third loop in the inner for-loop, and then the whole script stops. I, however, want the script to just continue calling subrpocesses until all the loops have looped.
So how to avoid this behavior?

EDIT:
Tried

```
try: 
   call and writes here
except:
   print "Ohai"
```

The actual output is two times an `ABORT` which is negated, which are in the main process of `runprogram`, but then an `ABORT` comes which is from a child process of `runprogram` and then the whole script fails. Maybe that has something to do with it?

Also, `"Ohai"` isn't printed...

Comment: Define failed. Does it fail in that it can't execute the runprogram or that the runprogram that is called fails. The subprocess call module shouldn't halt if a non-zero exit code is thrown. So I assume it has a problem with the actual subprocess call. Your best bet would be to throw it in a try/except loop.

Comment: May be put the failing system on a `try: except: pass`?